# Returning all json objects using asp net core 2.1

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-2.1

I am able to retrive one json object from a url.  I need help in retrieving a page full of json objects.  I found this site, https://jsoneditoronline.org/, to show the json architecture of the page I want to return:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkj1S.png)

Here is my code:

```
namespace iexName.Controllers
{
[Route("api/IexName")]
[ApiController]
public class IexNameController : ControllerBase
{
    private IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public IexNameController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Models.IexTradingStock> GetQuote()
    {
        string responseString = string.Empty;
        var Client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        try
        {
      responseString =   
  Client.GetStringAsync($"https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/chart/1y").Result;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(hre.Message);
            //TODO do something
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            //TODO do something
        }
        //quit if get content fail
        if (responseString == string.Empty) return null;

        try
        {
            var stock = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IexTradingStock> 
(responseString);
            return stock;

        }
```

The error is on "return stock;".  I realize I do not know how to return all of the json objects.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your desired JSON as text, rather than as a screen shot?  On stackoverflow we ask that questions include textual data such as code, error messages, exception details and data (JSON, XML, etc) as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3744182) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/3744182).

Comment: Here is the JSON data

date : 2017-10-02
open : 151.9623
high : 152.1494
low : 150.4452
close : 151.519
volume : 18698842
unadjustedVolume : 18698842
change : -0.305382
changePercent : -0.201
vwap : 151.2929
label : Oct 2, 17
changeOverTime : 0
 1  {12}
 2  {12}
 3  {12}

Answer (score 0):

Soon after I typed this into stackflow I realized what to do.  This worked.

```
namespace iexName.Controllers
{
[Route("api/IexName")]
[ApiController]
public class IexNameController : ControllerBase
{
    private IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public IexNameController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Models.IexTradingStock> GetQuote()
    {
        string responseString = string.Empty;
        var Client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        try
        {
            responseString = 
Client.GetStringAsync($"https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/chart/1y").Result;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(hre.Message);
            //TODO do something
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            //TODO do something
        }
        //quit if get content fail
        if (responseString == string.Empty) return null;

        try
        {` List<IexTradingStock> stock = 
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IexTradingStock>>(responseString);
            return stock;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            //TODO do something
            return null;
        }
    }
  }
}`
```